# Site URL for Facebook Like Button on Rails/Heroku: works on box but not on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, heroku, facebook-like

I've been trying to solve a site URL problem for Facebook-Like Button (similar to here [site URL for the facebook like button](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/q/2809350/986260)), but mine is specific to Rails or Heroku.

In rails I set the data-href in the html5 script to dynamic url:

data-href="<%= post_url(post) %>" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false"

From my box this works fine, capturing domain.com/posts as the url, but when deployed to Heroku, Facebook only picked up the domain.com

My Linter/Debugger passes with no issues.

Comment: I found out that adding the og:site_name meta supposedly makes it work. I did that but hasn't changed anything.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if it is because I have the like button on both the root and the post pages http://www.examples.com/ & http://www.examples.com/posts/cached_slug that messes up the way FB grabs the href tags?